# How do I pipe only certain results from a command to another or an If statement?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am trying to find a way to build a cron job that will log out idle users in OSX based on the last time they actively moved the mouse. OSX's built in functionality logs out everyone and only if the entire machine is idle. The only way I have been able to find out who is idle is by using 'w' which then gives me a few columns and one has idle time in it. How can I pipe only those numbers from that field and ignore the rest? Is there an easier way to do it?

How would I write this:

1.Issue command w

2.Check username to see if time idle is greater than 30 mins and if so
issue command ps -Ajc | grep loginwindow 
and find the username and the pid for loginwindow for that user who exceeded his idle time
and issue sudo kill -9 "whatever the pid is for that user's login window"

and exclude "whateverusernamehere" from this script (so that way it will stay logged in).

Comment: `kill -9` is an _extremely_ unfriendly command. Killed programs are unable to catch it and will fail to clean themselves up.

Comment: How does your `w` command show idle time? Mine is like `52.0s`, `10days` or `5:30` which proves difficult to compare against 30min. Maybe yours is more consistent. Knowing that I could write the script.

Comment: Not sure. I am using OSX 10.8.3. When I type w in terminal I get. Sorry not sure how to paste it without the formatting being changed.  "17:16  up 10:16, 6 users, load averages: 1.01 0.67 0.56"
"USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT"
SCCsu    console  -                 7:00   10:15 -
SCCsu    s000     -                17:15       1 bash
newell   s001     -                17:16       - w
hickam   console  -                14:58    2:18 -
Meirow   console  -                15:36    1:39 -
newell   console  -                17:15       - -"

Comment: note the button below your message http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16446807/edit . Also note the {} formatting tool at the top of the input box when you are in edit mode. Select your output and then click {}. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you asked about pipes. But the standard way to do this is:
Consider using the TMOUT variable.

Add something like this to the login profile:

```
declare -r TMOUT=14400
```

This logs out inactive interactive users after 14400 seconds, 4 hours of inactivity.

You solution, especially kill -9, is kind of harsh and can cause problems.  Some user can have a file open, your method will not detect that, and you kill the user off, you can corrupt the file.

Comment: Jim, Thank you very much for that. My problem is that these users are GUI users that are forgetting to log out. We use an RDP server to share desktops on the Mac that only has so many connection seats. Is there any way to kill their sessions in a friendly way?

Comment: We are treading in Mac waters here, which means my knowledge is limited. I do not know what Apple has done there, most likely there is something analgous. Googling finds: http://www.ehow.com/how_4577940_set-mac-log-out-automatically.html

Comment: Thanks Jim. That's what everyone suggests but it won't work unless all users are idle on the machine. So if a local user is at the machine or someone else logs in it resets the timer for the machine. So only if the machine sits for however long will it log out.